# spark-nlp 'JavaPackage' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, johnsnowlabs-spark-nlp

I am using jupyter lab to run spark-nlp text analysis. At the moment I am just running the sample code:

```
import sparknlp
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from sparknlp.pretrained import PretrainedPipeline
#create or get Spark Session
#spark = sparknlp.start()
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("ner")\
    .master("local[4]")\
    .config("spark.driver.memory","8G")\
    .config("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "2G") \
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "com.johnsnowlabs.nlp:spark-nlp_2.11:2.6.5")\
    .config("spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max", "500m")\
    .getOrCreate()
print("sparknlp version", sparknlp.version(), "sparkversion", spark.version)

#download, load, and annotate a text by pre-trained pipeline
pipeline = PretrainedPipeline('recognize_entities_dl', 'en')
result = pipeline.annotate('Harry Potter is a great movie')
```

I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-bfd6884be04c> in <module>
     15 
     16 #download, load, and annotate a text by pre-trained pipeline
---> 17 pipeline = PretrainedPipeline('recognize_entities_dl', 'en')
     18 result = pipeline.annotate('Harry Potter is a great movie')

~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sparknlp/pretrained.py in __init__(self, name, lang, remote_loc, parse_embeddings, disk_location)
     89     def __init__(self, name, lang='en', remote_loc=None, parse_embeddings=False, disk_location=None):
     90         if not disk_location:
---> 91             self.model = ResourceDownloader().downloadPipeline(name, lang, remote_loc)
     92         else:
     93             self.model = PipelineModel.load(disk_location)

~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sparknlp/pretrained.py in downloadPipeline(name, language, remote_loc)
     49     def downloadPipeline(name, language, remote_loc=None):
     50         print(name + " download started this may take some time.")
---> 51         file_size = _internal._GetResourceSize(name, language, remote_loc).apply()
     52         if file_size == "-1":
     53             print("Can not find the model to download please check the name!")

~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sparknlp/internal.py in __init__(self, name, language, remote_loc)
    190     def __init__(self, name, language, remote_loc):
    191         super(_GetResourceSize, self).__init__(
--> 192             "com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.pretrained.PythonResourceDownloader.getDownloadSize", name, language, remote_loc)
    193 
    194 

~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sparknlp/internal.py in __init__(self, java_obj, *args)
    127         super(ExtendedJavaWrapper, self).__init__(java_obj)
    128         self.sc = SparkContext._active_spark_context
--> 129         self._java_obj = self.new_java_obj(java_obj, *args)
    130         self.java_obj = self._java_obj
    131 

~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sparknlp/internal.py in new_java_obj(self, java_class, *args)
    137 
    138     def new_java_obj(self, java_class, *args):
--> 139         return self._new_java_obj(java_class, *args)
    140 
    141     def new_java_array(self, pylist, java_class):

~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/ml/wrapper.py in _new_java_obj(java_class, *args)
     67             java_obj = getattr(java_obj, name)
     68         java_args = [_py2java(sc, arg) for arg in args]
---> 69         return java_obj(*java_args)
     70 
     71     @staticmethod

TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable
```

I read a few of the github issues developers raised in spark-nlp repo, but the fixes are not working for me. I am wondering if the use of pyenv is causing problems, but it works for everything else.
My jupyter lab is launched like so:
`/home/myuser/.pyenv/shims/jupyter lab --no-browser --allow-root --notebook-dir /home/myuser/workdir/notebooks`

**My env configuration:**

ubuntu: `20.10`
Apache Spark: `3.0.1`
pyspark: `2.4.4`
spark-nlp: `2.6.5`
pyenv: `1.2.21`

Java:

```
openjdk 11.0.9 2020-10-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.9+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.9+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

jupyter:

```
jupyter core     : 4.7.0
jupyter-notebook : 6.1.5
qtconsole        : 5.0.1
ipython          : 7.19.0
ipykernel        : 5.4.2
jupyter client   : 6.1.7
jupyter lab      : 2.2.9
nbconvert        : 6.0.7
ipywidgets       : 7.5.1
nbformat         : 5.0.8
traitlets        : 5.0.5
```

I appreciate your help .. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove Spark 3.0.1, leave just PySpark 2.4.x. as Spark NLP still doesn't support Spark 3.x.  Use Java 8 instead of Java 11 because it's not supported in Spark 2.4.

Comment: I was going down that path, I removed spark from the classpath (SPARK_HOME does not point to 3.0.1 any more), downgraded to Java 8, However, I ran into some compatibility issues between pyspark 2.4.x and python 3.7.9. Here is what finally worked:
1) uninstall pyspark and spark-nlp
2) Remove SPARK_HOME from .bashrc exports
3) pip install pypandoc (solves compatibility issues mentioned above)
4) pip install pyspark==2.4.7
5) pip install spark-nlp
I wish some of these version requirements were documented on spark-nlp site